# GLib timeout memory management

Tags: python, memory-management, glib

I have a `GLib.timeout_add_seconds()` timer where I occasionally update the timeout interval, like this:

```
self.timer_id = GLib.timeout_add_seconds(interval, self.on_timeout, user_data)
...
def on_timeout(self, user_data):
    ...
    if change_timeout_interval:
        self.timer_id = GLib.timeout_add_seconds(new_interval, self.on_timeout, user_data)
        return False
    ...
```

So the ID for the new timer gets stored in the same `self.timer_id` variable and the old timer is removed (?) when I return false from the callback. I am worried about memory management, as discussed [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#mainloop-memory-management), especially because I am passing my `user_data` variable to the callback function. I only use `GLib.source_remove()` to remove the "final" timer ID, not all the previous ones that were replaced as shown above inside the callback function. Is this bad? If so, how could I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me. At the point you overwrite `self.timer_id` with the new timer ID, the old one is guaranteed to be eventually removed (and not dispatched again) by returning `False`.

Are you seeing any symptoms of problems, such as timers being dispatched multiple times, or leaks being shown by `valgrind --tool=memcheck`?

One small note: you can use `return GLib.SOURCE_REMOVE` rather than `return False` to make the code a little clearer. They’re equivalent. The converse is `return GLib.SOURCE_CONTINUE` rather than `return True`.

Comment: I think perhaps I was confused by the GLib docs: "There are two options for memory management of the user data passed to a GSource to be passed to its callback on invocation. ... This data is typically an object which ‘owns’ the timeout or idle callback, such as a widget or a network protocol implementation." I was thinking this was talking in particular about the data passed in the third argument, but maybe this is a more general comment.
There are a variety of memory leaks at the moment unfortunately, though perhaps this is not one of them!

Comment: The docs *are* talking about the `user_data` third argument, but since you’re using Python you shouldn’t have any issues with use-after-free. And because of your separate `GLib.source_remove()` call to remove the ‘final’ timer instance, you shouldn’t have issues with reference count loops either. 

The comments in the docs are more relevant to C programming.